# Metal - How to present drawable from scheduled handler callback

Tags: objective-c, metal

I'm working with Metal on MacOS and can't seem to find any clear documentation on the correct way to present a drawable without using the helper function on MTLCommandBuffer, presentDrawable (Which I cannot use due to the design of the application which is also trying to support multiple renderers and doesn't allow the class managing command buffers to know about the drawables directly).

[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1443029-presentdrawable?language=objc) state
 "The presentDrawable: method is a convenience method that calls addScheduledHandler: to present one drawable object." which seems to imply that presentDrawable just does this:

```
[buf addScheduledHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buf)
{
   [drawable present];
}];
```

While this does seem to actually present the rendering result it seems like there's something missing that the Metal framework expects to indicate the end of a frame because Xcode's "Capture GPU Frame" remains disabled for the lifetime of the app and the FPS counter in Xcode remains empty.

I've been looking online for what presentDrawable really does but can't seem to find any examples of usage of Metal other than extremely trivial samples that just use presentDrawable and MetalKit.

Comment: It may not be that "the Metal framework expects [anything] to indicate the end of a frame" just because Xcode is not seeing it. It may be that Xcode is hooking into the `-presentDrawable:` method itself to observe frames. In that case, there's literally nothing you could do other than calling it to get Xcode to notice. And Metal would be just fine. Note that any code you would want to call `[drawable present]` could also just create a dummy command buffer (unrelated to those you're using for rendering), call `-presentDrawable:` on it, and commit it.

Comment: I think you may be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of the difference in implementation between the two ways to present a drawable, but it may be the case that the `present` call doesn't signal a frame boundary. Have you tried explicitly calling `insertDebugCaptureBoundary()` on the command queue after you present the drawable?

Comment: insertDebugCaptureBoundary was exactly what was needed! I completely missed this method searching through the docs, the description for this method even calls out that Xcode normally attaches to presentDrawable